# make image slider full-width responsive

Tags: html, css, image, web, slider

I'm trying to make an image slider that is full-width responsive with HTML and CSS only. I am stuck at the moment on how to make the slider full-width responsive.

```css
.slides {
  padding: 0;
  width: 868px;
  height: 637px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.slides * {
  user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -khtml-user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

.slides input {
  display: none;
}

.slide-container {
  display: block;
}

.slide {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 868px;
  height: 637px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
}

.slides img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.nav label {
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: opacity .2s;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: 50pt;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 16px;
  line-height: 637px;
}

.slide:hover+.nav label {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.nav .next {
  right: 0;
}

input:checked+.slide-container .slide {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(1);
  transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

input:checked+.slide-container .nav label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="slides">
  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-1" checked />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img id src="assets/images/Slide/bilhete.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-6" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-2" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-2" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="assets/images/Slide/aplausos.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-1" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-3" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-3" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="assets/images/Slide/Pa%C3%A7os.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-2" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-4" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-4" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="assets/images/Slide/natal.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-3" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-5" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-5" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8055/8098750623_66292a35c0_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-4" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-6" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>

  <input type="radio" name="radio-btn" id="img-6" />
  <li class="slide-container">
    <div class="slide">
      <img src="http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8195/8098750703_797e102da2_z.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="nav">
      <label for="img-5" class="prev">&#x2039;</label>
      <label for="img-1" class="next">&#x203a;</label>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any help is going to be appreciated. I have to use CSS and HTML only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the widths to 100% in these two places:

```
.slides {
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 637px;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.slide {
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 637px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all .7s ease-in-out;
 }
```